# Gráfico utilizando local time em vez de GMT time

Tags: python

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dates
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


x = []
y = []

dataset = open("datasetDdos10Abril2017_unixtime.csv","r") ##separacao no csv eh por virgulas

for line in dataset:
    line = line.strip() #23,24\n -> 23,24 retira a quebra de linha
    X,Y = line.split(",") #separador eh a virgula
    x.append( float(X))
    y.append(float (Y))

dataset.close()


##
##x = [1491828000,1491828180,1491828360,1491828540,1491828720,1491828900,1491829080,1491829260,1491829440,1491829620,1491829800,1491829980,1491830160]
##
##y = [5284,4856,4880,4854,4903,4806,4873,4910,4914,4914,4944,4751,4863]
##

#k=datetime.now()
#k = datetime.fromtimestamp(x)
x1 = [datetime.now() + timedelta(microseconds=d/10) for d in x]


plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'))

plt.plot(x1, y, 'ro')

plt.title("Gráfico do número de Conexoes por segundo")
plt.ylabel("Numero de conexões por segundo")
plt.xlabel('Tempo')
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

O grafico gerado foi o seguinte:

[image: grafico]

O valor   1491828000 (unix time) corresponde a  April 10, 2017 9:40:00 AM (local time)

Como fazer para que no gráfico aparece 10/04/2017 9:40:00 em vez do horário e data de agora (datetime.now())?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apenas troque a conversão aqui:

```
x1 = [datetime.now() + timedelta(microseconds=d/10) for d in x]
```

Para:

```
x1 = [datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d)) for d in x]
```

Comment: x1 = [datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d)) for d in x], certo?

Comment: Sim, tem uma outra forma, mas teste essa por enquanto.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/208161/extraindo-os-valores-de-janela-e-hor%c3%a1rios-em-um-dump-de-rede

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/208271/gr%c3%a1fico-em-python-n%c3%a3o-exibe-os-valores-corretamente