# Extraindo os valores de Janela e horários em um dump de rede

Tags: python, python-3.x, segurança, python-2.7

O seguinte dump de rede (arquivo formato PCAP) é resultado da captura de um ataque de negação de serviço em laboratório:

[image: Ataques]

Gostaria de extrair o horário(unix time) e o valor da janela (win) e guardar em um arquivo texto, no seguinte formato:

horário,win

É possível com Python?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from scapy.all import *
import dpkt



filename='ataques.pcap'

a = rdpcap(filename)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a biblioteca [pycapfile](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypcapfile):

```
> pip install pypcapfile
```

Uso:

```
>>> from pcapfile import savefile
>>> testcap = open('ataques.pcap', 'rb')
>>> capfile = savefile.load_savefile(testcap, verbose=True)
```

As informações que você precisa estão em `capfile.packets`. Faça um `capfile.packets[0].__dir__()` para obter as propriedades que deseja. Acredito que `timestamp` seja uma delas.

Comment: uma vez extraido o timestamp e a janela, como salva-los separados por vírgulas em um arquivo texto?

Comment: Então, eu não sei quais são os campos de janela e tempo nesse arquivo. Precisaria deles pra montar um exemplo de como salvar.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/5zEuaQcf

https://ibb.co/jzYDXa

Time stamp eu achei mas win parece que pycapfile não mostra!

Comment: Está dentro de `packet`, provavelmente.

Answer (score 1):

A maneira mais simples é com tshark:

```
tshark -r "1.pcap" -Tfields -e frame.time_epoch -e tcp.window_size_value >> arquivo.txt
```