# Gráfico em Python não exibe os valores corretamente

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tentando aprender a fazer gráficos em Python. Fiz um agora e não ficou muito bom:

[image: grafico]

Todas as datas são em 10 de Abril de 2017, viriando apenas o horário que vai de 07h50:00 até 08h40:00 (GMT -3h)
Na figura, apareceu até a data de hoje e,em função disso, sumiram os pontos.No eixo do tempo (eixo X) era para aparecer apenas a data de 10 de Abril de 2017 com a variaçao de hora,minuto e segundo! Este é o problemaComo consertar?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.dates as dates
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta


    x = []
    y = []

    dataset = open("dataset_semAtaques.csv","r") ##separacao no csv eh por virgulas

    for line in dataset:
        line = line.strip() #23,24\n -> 23,24 retira a quebra de linha
        X,Y = line.split(",") #separador eh a virgula
        x.append( float(X))
        y.append(float (Y))

    dataset.close()


    x1 = [datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d)) for d in x]


    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'))

    plt.plot(x1, y, 'ro')

    plt.title("Gráfico do número de Conexões por segundo antes do Ataque")
    plt.ylabel("Numero de conexões por segundo")
    plt.xlabel('Tempo')
    plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
    plt.show()
```

O arquivo dataset_semAtaques.csv segue abaixo:

```
1491821400,0
1491821580,0
1491821760,0
1491821940,0
1491822120,3
1491822300,3
1491822480,2
1491822660,2
1496012764,3
1491823020,2
1491823200,2
1491823380,2
1491823560,3
1491823740,2
1491823920,2
1491824100,2
1491824280,3
1491824400,2
```

Comment: Eu não consegui reproduzir o problema: http://imgur.com/a/8Fncw

Comment: @Luiz Vieira: no eixo do tempo era para aparecer apenas a data de 10 de Abril de 2017 com a variaçao de hora,minuto e segundo! Este é o problema

Comment: Bom, da próxima vez, explique-se melhor. :) A sua figura, inclusive, não ajuda nesse entendimento.

Answer (score 7):

Simplesmente defina os limites do eixo x usando a função [`set_xlim`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim.html), como no exemplo abaixo:

```
# . . .
plt.title("Grafico do numero de Conexoes por segundo antes do Ataque")
plt.ylabel("Numero de conexoes por segundo")
plt.xlabel('Tempo')

# Linha adicionada:
plt.gca().set_xlim([datetime(2017, 4, 10, 0, 0, 0), datetime(2017, 4, 10, 23, 59, 59)])

plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5):

> Na figura, apareceu até a data de hoje e,em função disso, sumiram os pontos.

Não sumiram não. Experimente ampliar a imagem. Eles estão nas bordas.

Converti uma das suas datas para o formato sugerido e note que não há informação dos milissegundos nela:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1491821400).strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
'04/10/2017 05:50:00.000000'
```

Na geração do CSV, verifique o formato de data. Pode não ser suficiente para o seu gráfico.